# Clustering coefficients of sum-of-sine regression models

Tags: regression, clustering

I am trying to cluster different time series, based on coefficients yielded by [sinusoidal regression](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Statistics2/sinusoidal.html). In my case, I have a number of time series of equal length and I fit a sinusoidal regression with a fixed number of terms to each individual time series. For simplification, let's use two sine terms. The model would look something like this:

$y = a_1 \sin(b_1 x + c_1) + a_2 \sin(b_2 x + c_2)$

This model would yield a vector of coefficients of length 6 with the following shape: $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ b_1 \\ c_1 \\ a_2 \\ b_2 \\ c_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

After fitting all time series, I would like to cluster time series based on the yielded coefficients. Now, the problem is that the order in which the terms appear is arbitrary. Two time series could be very similar, but the different waves could be encoded in different terms. For example, two coefficient vectors could look like this:

`(1 1 1 2 2 2)` and `(2 2 2 1 1 1)`

Obviously, these two coefficient vectors describe the same sum-of-sine model for a given window of $x$, but how would I apply a clustering algorithm that would also find these vectors to be the same?

**Possible solutions I have considered:**

"Ordering" the resulting coefficients by magnitude of the `a` coefficients (keeping each sin term together), but that decision seems quite arbitrary.

Another possible solution I have considered is to calculate a "cross-ratio" of all sub-terms: In the case of three sine terms I would first order all $a$ coefficients in descending order and then calculate $\bigl(\frac{a_1}{a_2} + \frac{a_1}{a_3} + \frac{a_2}{a_3}\bigr)$. I would to the same for each sub term $a$, $b$, and $c$ and then cluster the resulting ratios. Is this viable?